# React import leads to Failed to resolve module specifier "react"

Tags: reactjs

Call me stupid (and I will not take it personally), but I have not used REACT for over 3 years, and my brain cells must have died.

I am getting the error:

> localhost/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I am sure it has to do with how I am using the import in Chrome.

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <script src="../node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="Main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from 'App'


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />, 
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Main.js**

(after babel cli, with react preset)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from 'App';
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById("root"));
```

**App.jsx** (located in same folder as Main.jsx (and babel creates App.js in same folder as Main.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Might be related to this: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14635

Comment: @codecubed.io it appears so, but then the cjs import does not work either, so what should I be doing?

Comment: Is there a reason you have: `react.development.js` rather than `react.js`?

Comment: Like I said, I have not used REACT for three years. The first example I saw was using development, which I assumed would give me better debug.

Comment: I took out the type="module" and now they load, the error is now different.

Comment: It looks like all in the umd folder is production vs development. I thought development sounded better.

Comment: Ah my bad I read it as "I've been using React for three years". Might be easier to get up and running with CRA in that case.

Comment: yes, I tried CRA, (we have firewall issues with it). I updated the issue, and now I have a more mysterious bug.

Comment: I think your babel setup is probably wrong.

Comment: Do you see anything wrong in how it transpiled main.jsx?

Comment: Where's `App`? And unless you're using a module bundler like Webpack, you shouldn't be including those import statements.

Comment: Not using bundler yet (one step at a time, please). Updated original message to show App.jsx

Comment: Then ditch the react import statements (it should already be globally exposed by the tag-based imports you have above), and convert your your `App` import to either absolute (`'/'`), or relative paths (`'./'`,`'../'`) and include the file extension. Keep in mind, this will only be supported in modern browsers. Otherwise import them individually with script tags, or move the code into a single file.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk that worked, needed to also remove //import { Component } from 'react', and make change Component to : class App extends React.Component

Comment: I am looking at bundlers now, This keeps changing on me, but I am looker at Parcel (first choice, I like simplicity), then Rollup. Any recommendation?

Comment: I've only ever worked with Webpack myself so can't speak much to that, but I'd go with whichever best suites your needs.

Comment: i have been searching for this question for so long, thank you for asking it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you're not using a module bundler like Webpack, you can ditch the react import statements (it should already be globally exposed by the tag-based imports you have above), convert your `App` import to either absolute (`'/'`), or relative paths (`'./'`,`'../'`) and include the file extension. To support older browsers incompatible with ES6 modules, import it instead with a script tag, or move the whole code into a single file.

Comment: are there any downside to just always using tags?  seems just so much easier and less moving parts...

Comment: The downside is multiple network calls for resources. The benefit to bundlers like webpack is they combine all your assets to reduce round trips. Typically also provides for stricter typing and better code completion.

Answer (score 8):

When you load the React script using a  tag as in your example then the React and ReactDOM objects are already available to you.

In order to use Reacts components and functions you just use them straight away without any import calls. All you need to do is prepend your use with "**React.**" i.e.

```
React.Component
React.useState
```

and so on.

Comment: are there any downside to just always using tags?  seems just so much easier and less moving parts...

Comment: @mike01010 It's subjective. If your project is simple then loading React through script tags (either from your local server or from CDN) is sufficient. If your project grows and involves many third party modules and libraries then having everything loaded through gabazillion of tags no longer makes sense and will cause troubles. To name few you will endup with namespace conflicts, duplicate functions, overcrowded global space etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error (below), as I was mistakenly running my app using `Live Server` instead of using `Bundler`(like Parcel or Webpack).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Just wanted to highlight this as it caught me out, and hopefully can save other beginners some time figuring out why it doesn't work.