# Jest unit test ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, reactjs.net

I've been working on an ASP.Net core application where I have added React components. I've been trying to add React unit tests and it's been real challenging but I feel like I'm getting close. The latest error I'm getting is "**ReferenceError: React is not defined**" when executing npm test.

I added "**import React from 'react';**" at the top of my jsx file and the test executed fine. The problem is when I try run my application, I now get:

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**

Coming from a .NET background, I'm not used to having to install a whole bunch of third party packages to get things working. I'm probably missing something.

```js
import React from 'react';    //This causes an error in my application but fixes my unit test error

export class MyReactComponent extends React.Component {    
...
}
```

```js
import { MyReactComponent } from "../wwwroot/src/react/myReactComponent.jsx"
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe("Test", () => {
    it("myTest", () => {                
        render(<MyReactComponent />);       
    });
});
```

**package.json**

```
 {
      "name": "bs.bsw1.portal",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.8",
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
        "nodejs": "^0.0.0",
        "react": "^18.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.17.10",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "@testing-library/dom": "^8.17.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
        "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
        "@types/node": "^18.7.5",
        "jest": "^28.1.3",
        "jest-editor-support": "^30.1.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.3",
        "mocha": "8.3.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --verbose ./__tests__"
      },
      "jest": {
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "type": "module"
    }
```

**babel.config.cjs**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "10"
                }
            }               
        ],
        ["@babel/preset-react", {
          "runtime": "automatic"
       }]
    ]   
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980934/referenceerror-react-is-not-defined-in-jest-tests

Comment: @uditkumar11I have seen that link. I have that code already in my babel.config.cjs. Maybe unrelated, I'm not sure if I should have a babel.config.cjs, babel.config.js, or babel.config.json.

Comment: have a look at this https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#babelconfigjson
This will give you an idea about how and what to use

Comment: The other solution in the above link was to add "import React from 'react';" to the jsx file. Like I mentioned, this fixes the test but causes my application to break.

Comment: whats the error ? Check if the error if already fixed by someone else u can post a new question.

Comment: @uditkumar11 The error message is in my original post.

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693992/react-import-leads-to-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-react